# Removing same values from a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dataset, duplicate-data

Could anybody help me for avoiding this issue. My issue is that i have one dataset that populates some values like value1, value2, value3, value1, value3, etc. And i am showing this values in a dropdown list. But my requirement is that i have to show the same value once. That is the dropdown should be display like this, value1, value2, value3. Not repeat the existing value. Please help me for implement this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the data set come from? Are you querying it? You can remove the dupes at that point... or, you can check if the value exists while adding it... there are many possibilities here but you haven't shown any code.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a programming assignment.

Comment: People will be much more likely to help if you demonstrate that you have already tried to solve the problem yourself. Do can you post your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping through your data, add to another list/array.  If it already exists there, don't add it.  Use the resulting list.

Use Distinct if you are using SQL...e.g.  Select Distinct column1 from table where...

Answer (score 1):

How are you populating the dataset? From a sql query? in memory data source? If SQL, use the DISTINCt keyword.

If in memory, LINQ can perform distinct operations.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

using sql or linq use group by.